# Java confusion initializing variables within different cases

Tags: java, math

My source code is below I am attempting to create a program that will calculate the area diameter and circumference of a circle when my user enters A,C, or D. I only want to return the correct response depending on the user input. I managed to get all three to return within my first case earlier but separating them proved difficult any ideas?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("This program will determine the Area, Circumference or Diameter for a circle. Type A for area C for Circumference and D for Diameter"); // Prompt for user input of capitol character

        while (!sc.hasNext("[A-Z]+")) {
            System.out.println(sc.next().charAt(0) + " is not a capital letter! Non Alphanumeric values are not permitted."); // error response for any unnaceptable character A-Z is specified as the range of acceptable characters
        }

        char c = ' ';
        c = sc.next().charAt(0); // looking through user input at character at position 0

        switch (c) {

        case 'A':
            System.out.print("Enter the radius: "); //I am storing the entered radius in floating point
            float radius = sc.nextFloat();
            float area = ((float) Math.PI) * ((float)(radius * radius));
            System.out.printf("The area of the circle is: %.2f \n", area);
            break;

        case 'C':
            System.out.print("Enter the radius: "); //I am storing the entered radius in floating point
            float circumference = ((float)(Math.PI * 2 * radius));
            System.out.printf("The circumference of the circle is: %.2f \n", circumference);
            break;

        case 'D':
            System.out.print("Enter the radius: "); //I am storing the entered radius in floating point
            float diameter = ((float)(radius * 2));
            System.out.printf("The diameter of the circle is: %.2f \n", diameter);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What about placing a `while(true)` that will contain your `while (!sc.hasNext("[A-Z]+"))` and your `switch`?

Answer (score 1):

You define and calculate `float radius = sc.nextFloat();` inside `case 'A':` but `radius` is used in the two other cases. In a switch only one case is executed (when there is no fall though), Therefor, when you select case 'C' or 'D' the radius variable is never defined and you'll get an error.

To solve this, define and calculate `radius` outside the switch

```
...

float radius = sc.nextFloat();
switch (c) {

case 'A':
    System.out.print("Enter the radius: "); //I am storing the entered radius in floating point
    float area = ((float) Math.PI) * ((float)(radius * radius));
    System.out.printf("The area of the circle is: %.2f \n", area);
    break;

case 'C':
    System.out.print("Enter the radius: "); //I am storing the entered radius in floating point
    float circumference = ((float)(Math.PI * 2 * radius));
    System.out.printf("The circumference of the circle is: %.2f \n", circumference);
    break;

case 'D':
    System.out.print("Enter the radius: "); //I am storing the entered radius in floating point
    float diameter = ((float)(radius * 2));
    System.out.printf("The diameter of the circle is: %.2f \n", diameter);
    break;
}
...
```